# Saving user in Firebase with display name

Tags: firebase, axios

I have an app in React and I m using Firebase and I make requests with Axios.
I want to save users with display name, email and password. I mention that I don t have Firebase via NPM and I m using Realtime Database.
Is it possible to save data like that with Axios only or I need to add Firebase to NPM?

Answer (score 0):

I actually found a way without using Firebase via NPM.
When I signed up I had an extra field with display name even though it was selected for email/password type and I noticed that when I got a response in return `displayName` was there with the value also for signing in.

Since I got this `displayName` as a response for signing in and signing up I can use it in my app when posting/commenting. I could have pushed a new user in database with personalized fields but I wanted to do it the other way.